# I cannot find Disk Utility tool

Tags: 12.04

How come I cannot find disk-utility tool on (1)dash search (2)system setting?. I already finish to upgrade my system to newest version.

Can you help me to find it?.
My *Ubuntu* system is: *Ubuntu 12.04 LTS*.

Comment: Could you add the output of the commands `apt-cache policy gnome-disk-utility` and `ls -l /usr/bin/palimpsest`?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have an alternative tool for your needs. That is: *Gparted*. One of the most widely accepted one. I would insist you one installing it in your *Linux* machine for your needs.

Go to your *Terminal* and type the command
`sudo apt-get install gparted`

Answer (score 0):

try gnome-disk-utility ? in the terminal type
which gnome-disk-utility

this may not be the name in ubuntu, it's what I got from the fedora machine I'm at.